# How to change gridview's column format type and format string on runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

If the user does not have authorization, I want to show the price with a special character instead of a numeric.

I can change the formattype and formatstring in the code block below, but when I try to get the formatstring of the changed column. `colPRICE.DisplayFormat.GetFormatString()` is equal to `{0}`, `{0}` accepts only a numeric value. How can I squash `{0}` ?

```
 colPRICE.DisplayFormat.FormatType = FormatType.Custom;
 colPRICE.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "";
 var formatStringPrice = colPRICE.DisplayFormat.GetFormatString();

 for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
 {
     gridView1.SetRowCellValue(i, "PRICE", "****");
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leave the formatting as is and handle CustomDrawCell event for the GridView.

Something like this:

```
private void gridView1_CustomDrawCell(object sender, RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e) 
{
   if (!DoesUserHaveAuth())
   {
     e.DisplayText = "******";
   }
}
```

---